# Laravel5 status 500

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5, cloud9

I've been trying to import an existing Laravel project on the Cloud9 IDE. I set up and installed everything required but fail to load the web. The developer console shows "**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**"

Lot of people said it is about the written permission for the "storage" and "bootstraps" folder, so I gave written permission for all files in the whole workspace, but still it gave the same error. I checked the apache error log but can't see the corresponding log. Also, normal PHP files(hello world) are loaded successfully but not the Laravel related pages. The code of public/index.php:

> require **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
>
> $app = require_once **DIR**.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
>
> $kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
>
> $response = $kernel->handle(
>       $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture() );
>
> $response->send();
>
> $kernel->terminate($request, $response);

The status 500 error appears on **$response->send();**

Comment: Check your `storage/logs` folder for more stack trace

Comment: what is the error in your `error_log` ?

Comment: is there any errors on your storage/logs/laravel.log file?

Comment: it said "production.ERROR: RuntimeException: The only supported ciphers are AES-128-CBC and AES-256-CBC with the correct key lengths. "